# How do I seperate an array of IPC values

Tags: node.js, electron, ipc

So I'm **VERY** new to NodeJS and Electron and I've made a login system using IPC where the input data is sent to the backend:

```
loginBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var loginData =  {
        username: document.getElementById('username').value,
        password: document.getElementById('password').value
      };
    ipc.send('login', loginData)
})
```

And the result if i print it to the console (`console.log(arg)`)is:
`{ password: 'testpass', username: 'test' }` so now how do I separate it because I can't figure it out?
I've tried using `console.log(arg[0])` to try and get the data that would be kept in `document.getElementById('username').value` but it doesn't work

Comment: `arg` looks like an object so you access its properties using dot notation just like you already did with for example `.value` so it's `arg.username`

Comment: Thank you I found out just as you posted that lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so turns out I'm just being stupid I asked a friend and its `console.log(arg.username)` so yeah XD